# display output in `ascending` or `descending` order after storing value using linked list in c

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am storing five different values using from user input. And displaying as it is inserted from the command prompt, now I want to organize the `output` as `ascending` or `descending` order during display. I searched for this, but I am getting more complicated examples. My code is pretty simple. I am learning. Till now, what I did already, if I can implement `ascending` or `descending` order in my code, then it will be more help to me for easy understand. Would someone help me please to do this, if possible in my existing code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct list{
    int value;
    struct list *next;
};

int main(){

    struct list list1[5], *c;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("Enter value of list %d = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &list1[i].value);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        list1[i].next = &list1[i+1];
    }
    list1[4].next = NULL;

    c = &list1[0];
    while(c != NULL){
        printf("List value: %d\n", c->value);
        c = c->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it may be due to the lack of allocating memory to the members of list1 array.  Modify the loop and just use the more conventional way of inserting into a linked list.

Comment: In which way do you want to _organize_ the values - a) by moving them to array positions according to the order, or b) by changing the `next` pointers accordingly?

Comment: b)by changing the `next` pointers accordingly

Comment: hi, are you still on into that question ?? i could  write code for you then ..

Comment: I have gone through different process, but is that possible in this way as @Armali said in b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> … implement `ascending` or `descending` order in my code … by changing the next pointers accordingly

You could use a kind of insertion sort to do this by going through your unsorted list and building a new list, reconnecting the `next` pointers in sorted order:

```
    struct list *head = NULL, *nc;  // new (initially empty) list starts at head
    for (c = list1; c; c = nc)      // go through original list
    {
        struct list **pred = &head, *d;
        while ((d=*pred) && c->value > d->value) pred = &d->next;   // find pos.
        nc = c->next;               // get next element (before overwritten)
        c->next = d, *pred = c;     // insert element into sorted list
    }
```

This sorts ascending; for descending order, change `>` to `<`.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the data in order instead.  can follow this code to store data in sorted order :=

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct List
{
 struct List * next;
 int node;
};

struct List * add(struct List * head, int data)
{
  struct List * newnode = (struct List *)malloc(sizeof(struct List));
  newnode->next = NULL;
  newnode->node = data;

 /* if list is empty (initially), put value  */
  if(head == NULL)
  {
     head = newnode;
     return head;
 }    
  /* if head itself smaller than the node to be inserted 
     the sign(<) has to be changed(>) for ascending order.
  */
 else if(head->node > data)
{
   newnode->next = head;
   head = newnode;

   return head;
 }
 struct List * temp = head;
 struct List * current = NULL;

 while(temp->next)
 {
     current = temp;
    /*if node is fitted between current node and next of current node..
        the sign(>=) has to be changed(<=) and the sign (<=) has to be changed                     (>=)for ascending order .
     */
    if(current->node <= data && current->next->node >= data)
    {
        newnode->next = current->next;
        current->next = newnode;
        return head;
    }
    temp = temp->next;
}
temp->next = newnode;

return head;
}

void display(struct List * head)
{
 if(head == NULL)
     return;

  printf("%i ", head->node);

  display(head->next);
 }
 int main(void){
   int arr[] = {3, 0, 1, 4, 2};
   int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(1);
   struct List * head = NULL;

  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    head = add(head, arr[i]);
  }

  display(head);
  printf("\n");
}
```